# React Native Download folder from url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on React native and trying to download folder from url.
Is it possible?
Downloading file should be done with RNFetchBlob.

I can download all files in folder but it takes a lot of time.
And is there any possible way for downloading 30000 files quickly?
These are all thumbnails so it small.

Thanks for your kind attention.

```
      let thumbs = []
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
    thumbs.push(this.downloadThumb(this.state.thumbs[skip + i]))
  }
  Promise.all(thumbs)
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        totalCount: this.state.totalMarkerCount,
        fetchedCount: skip + count
      })
      console.log(`recursive_thumb ${skip + count}`)
      this.recursive_thumb(skip + count, count)
    })
    .catch(reason => {
      this.setState({
        totalCount: this.state.totalMarkerCount,
        fetchedCount: skip + count
      })
      this.recursive_thumb(skip + count, count)
    })
```

It's my code for improve download speed.